# How to find line number from Stack Trace

Tags: ios, exception

```
[3021:200369] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'
```

> *** First throw call stack: (0x2a04c0d7 0x386e8c77 0x29f5dcf7 0x2d7c44d3 0x4760bb 0xb46c7 0x29b89f31 0x29b89eeb 0x29b89fdd
>   0x29a9d3e7 0x29b3b12d 0x29a8e111 0x29f5b141 0x29a8dfcb 0x29a8de91
>   0x29a8dd2d 0x2a01200f 0x2a011423 0x2a00faa1 0x29f5b6d1 0x29fa509b
>   0xb3c85 0x191819b 0x1920d89 0x191aac5 0x1922b1b 0x1923e21 0x38dfad9d
>   0x38dfaaf0) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException

I want To know Where its crashing like method name or line number, I have not created any array with count 3.

Comment: Add exception Breakpoint   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode    refer this link for adding exception breakpoints

Comment: The count is 4, not 3. Index 4 refers to a non-existent _fifth_ element.

Comment: You should be able to symbolicate the stack trace from within Xcode.  You need to keep hold of the archives you use to submit apps, as they contain the `.dsym` "file" containing the stripped symbol info.

Comment: After adding break point I'm getting crash at below line of code                                CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[self.atableviewcellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];